# How to fix MySql.Data.MySqlClient Error in visual studio?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio, xampp

I've Imported `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` but the Visual Studio wont recognize it. I already installed MySql Connector and MySql for Visual Studio but I reinstall and it fixes the problem. However, when I start my program in visual studio the problem will pop up again and I don't know how to fix this. Sorry for my bad English.

When I start the program this error will pop:

> Warning   1   The primary reference "MySql.Data, Version=8.0.18.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d,
>   processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it was built
>   against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" framework. This is a higher
>   version than the currently targeted framework
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5". LogIn

Comment: I think you just need to change the version of your project to use .NET 4.5.2. It's under the project properties. Note that you will need .NET 4.5.2 on the target machine (where you use your project) too.

Comment: Following on from the suggestion by Jacob H, you should check [Runtime Changes for Migration from .NET Framework 4.5 to 4.5.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/runtime/4.5-4.5.2) just in case one of the changes applies to your code. It's unlikely, but best to be forewarned.